# Does Killing Mohg lock you out of certain quest lines, items, or other things?

Tags: elden-ring

I just beat Stormveil Castle and more than halfway done with Rani's and Blaidd's quest.

I decided to farm runes where the boss Mohg is located and I'm thinking of fighting him.

Based on where I currently am story wise, if I beat Mohg, what quest lines, items, or anything else could I miss or possibly lock myself out of?

Comment: There's 2 Mohg([Mohg, the Omen](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Mohg,+the+Omen) and [Mohg, Lord of Blood](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Mohg,+Lord+of+Blood)) in this game. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: Ah didn't know. I'm referring to the Lord of blood.

Answer (score 1):

There is no questline related to Mohg, Lord of Blood. So you can kill it when you can.